# How to quickly add soap to counter soap dispenser?

Tags: cleaning

I've got granite counters with your basic top mounted soap dispenser.  It really takes a half hour to get all of the soap into it.  Unscrewing it is a HUGE pain and is faster but messy.  Any way to make this process quicker?

Comment: When I fill ours I just pour some soap in from the top. I don't try to fill it up because that has resulted in overfills. Sometimes it is slow though; and sticking a straw down in the hole while pouring would probably speed it up. I'll have to give that a try.

Comment: What about adding soap before it's completely empty?  Maybe top it off once a week/month, depending on your usage.

Comment: @Tester101 - this is a bi-weekly thing at my house.  Is there no solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Get a plastic funnel and glue a drinking straw to the inside of the spout. This will let the air out while it fills.

Or, buy another under-sink bottle. You can fill that bottle quickly, then turn it upside down and put it in the hole. Just let it sit until empty.

Comment: I thought about a funnel and straw but that seems weird to have an accessory to add soap by your sink.  Our sink has garbage disposal and pipes in front of dispenser meaning that you have to be a contortionist to screw it in.

Comment: I really don't understand why you are removing the bottle from underneath to fill it. Why not fill it from the top?